# Show total of dynamic variables (php and javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, variables, addition

I have a form that includes 2 range inputs to set $ target values (as in the code below.) On submit the form stores these to a database. The stored values per slider are initially displayed however javascript show newly selected values as the range slider moves.

I'm now trying to dynamically show a total of the 2 range inputs, i.e. show a total based on the stored values however, if a range slider is moved the total should also dynamically change.

```
<label for="monday">Monday - $<span id="monday"><?php echo number_format($set_monday) ?> </span></label>
<?php  if (!empty($set_monday)) { ?> 
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="monday" name="monday" value=<?php echo $set_monday ?> step="100" oninput="showValue1(this.value)" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="monday" name="monday" value="0" step="50" oninput="showValue1(this.value)" />
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> function showValue1(newValue) { document.getElementById("monday").innerHTML=newValue;} </script>


<label for="tuesday">Tuesday - $<span id="tuesday"><?php echo number_format($set_tuesday) ?></span></label>
<?php  if (!empty($set_tuesday)) { ?> 
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="tuesday" name="tuesday" value=<?php echo $set_tuesday ?> step="100" oninput="showValue2(this.value)" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="tuesday" name="tuesday" value="0" step="50" oninput="showValue2(this.value)" />
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> function showValue2(newValue) { document.getElementById("tuesday").innerHTML=newValue;} </script>


<label>Total Target = $
<?php
$sum_total = $set_monday + $set_tuesday;
echo number_format($sum_total);
?>
</label>
```

I cant work out how to add the output of the functions and mix adding php and javascript variables, can anyone help?

Comment: FYI: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the spans inside the labels and the input IDs are the same, that is wrong. Make sure the HTML elements have unique IDs. Also, javascript is needed to calculate the sum dynamically. Based on this, your code should look like this:

```
<label for="monday">Monday - $<span id="monday"><?php echo number_format($set_monday) ?> </span></label>
<?php  if (!empty($set_monday)) : ?> 
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="mondayRange" name="monday" value=<?php echo $set_monday ?> step="100" oninput="showValue(this)" />
<?php else : ?>

<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="mondayRange" name="monday" value="0" step="50" oninput="showValue(this)" />
<?php endif; ?>

<label for="tuesday">Tuesday - $<span id="tuesday"><?php echo number_format($set_tuesday) ?></span></label><br>
<?php if (!empty($set_tuesday)) : ?> 
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="tuesdayRange" name="tuesday" value=<?php echo $set_tuesday ?> step="100" oninput="showValue(this)" />
<?php else : ?>
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" id="tuesdayRange" name="tuesday" value="0" step="50" oninput="showValue(this)" />
<?php endif; ?>


<label id="total">Total Target = $
<?php
$sum_total = $set_monday + $set_tuesday;
echo number_format($sum_total);
?>
</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue(range)
    {
        var sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('mondayRange').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('tuesdayRange').value);

        document.getElementById(range.id.substr(0, range.id.length - 5)).innerHTML = range.value;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'Total Target = $' + sum;
    }
</script>
```